# Python Numpy - Image Array - Re-Order Rows

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I would like to re-order the rows of an image.
Is it possible to do this.

Ideally I would like to place each row to its nearest neighouring row with the closest amount of pixels.
I am trying to solve a cryptic puzzle.

Its jumbled rows of an image which should be some text.
I dont yet know the algorith they have used to crypt this therfore a start with the above would be ideal.

Would appriciate any help, cheers.

```
a = Image.open("NEW.png")
a = numpy.array(a)

#re order the rows here

#save sorted image and display
a = Image.fromarray(a)
a.save("SORTED.png")
#a.show()
```

Comment: Is the image black and white, or is it full-color? Can you upload the example somewhere? Be warned, this is a fairly complex problem, because for each row in the image, there will be multiple rows that are "close" in terms of pixel-value location similarity.